# What is the difference between impl Trait and T for T: Trait?

Tags: rust

In the [Rust book Chapter 10.2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html), they introduced `impl Trait` as simply syntactic sugar for `T where T: Trait`. It seems like there are subtle difference between the two as `test1` in the following code does not compile:

```rust
fn test1<T: Fn() -> ()>() -> T {
    || {}
}

fn test2() -> impl Fn() -> () {
    || {}
}
```

Result:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:2:5
  |
1 | fn test1<T: Fn() -> ()>() -> T {
  |          -                   -
  |          |                   |
  |          |                   expected `T` because of return type
  |          |                   help: consider using an impl return type: `impl Fn() -> ()`
  |          this type parameter
2 |     || {}
  |     ^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found closure
  |
  = note: expected type parameter `T`
                    found closure `[closure@src/lib.rs:2:5: 2:7]`
  = help: every closure has a distinct type and so could not always match the caller-chosen type of parameter `T`
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=efff18d27117a9bb4006f24aa969486d)

What are these differences and what's the intuitive way of thinking about them?

Comment: Be careful not to mix up the "Traits as Parameters" and "Returning Types that Implement Traits" sections. Parameters and return types have different rules.